# Get the name of the functions called by a class

Tags: java, class, function, reflection

There are `two classes A and B` in the same package.

how to get name of the functions of class A called by class B.

Restriction is that the **code of A and B cannot be modified**.

Comment: It is unclear what is being asked, please update your question to make what you are attempting to do more clear. Also please post code of what you have tried.

Comment: Do you want to do this at runtime? By static analysis? With what you've posted so far this is not a real question by SO standards.

Comment: @JimGarrison I want to do this by static analysis.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use Java reflection to do static code analysis tasks like this.  The reflection APIs don't provide the information that is needed.

Off the top of my head, I can think of two approaches that will work:

- If you only have the ".class" files, then you can use a bytecode library such as BCEL to load the classes and traverse them to identify all of the method calls.
- If you have source code, you could also use some existing Java parser library to create ASTs for your code and analyse them.

(The first approach is probably simpler if all you want is a list of class and method names.)

Answer (score 1):

Reflection can be very useful, but very complicated if you don't understand it.

If you have the name of the class, and want to print the methods:

```
Class c = Class.forName(the_class_name);

for(Method m : c.getMethods()) {
  System.out.println(m.toString());
}
```

If you want the name of a class given any Object:

```
String className = the_object.getClass().getName();
```

A combination of the two could look like this:

```
for(Method m : the_object.getClass().getMethods())
  System.out.println(m.toString());
```

I think what you are asking for is the names of all the methods from `A` that `B` calls.

That can't really be done with reflection, mostly because Java doesn't provide any method for doing this.

[The API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), as always, provides more information. If you look through there, you might come up with a simple work around.

Answer (score 1):

"Class of all the functions called by class A or class B" is confusing. But, If You want to get the class and function name of caller to a method `detectsName` described in your class `A` , then following code will be useful to you.

```
public class A {
    public void detectsName() {
        Throwable t = new Throwable();
        StackTraceElement traceLine = t.getStackTrace()[1];
        // t.printStackTrace();
        String className = traceLine.getClassName();
        String methodName = traceLine.getMethodName();
        int lineNumber = traceLine.getLineNumber();
        System.out.println(className);
        System.out.println(methodName);
        System.out.println(lineNumber);
    }
}
```

If you call this method from any other class say - B, it will be detected.

```
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.detectsName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Dependency Finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/Manual.html) can do queries for this. Its approach is to generate meta data in XML and then use regexp based comparison.  You may be specifically looking for feature called 'closure' with inbound reference..